# wget works without sudo, but when using with sudo returns an OpenSSL error

Tags: 22.04, wget, openssl

Screenshot of what happens:
[image: can wget without sudo, but sudo returns OpenSSL error]

I've been trying to search for the error online, but none seems to work

```
(base) sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for josaphat: 
--2022-10-29 12:36:47--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
OpenSSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory
OpenSSL: error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file
OpenSSL: error:05880002:x509 certificate routines::system lib
OpenSSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory
OpenSSL: error:10080002:BIO routines::system lib
OpenSSL: error:0A080002:SSL routines::system lib
Disabling SSL due to encountered errors.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Also, why would you ever want to or need to run `wget` as root? Just don't run it as root and you won't have an issue. You are storing the file in your own home directory so you _really_ don't want it to be owned by root which is what will happen if `sudo` worked.

Comment: The problem is when i wanted to install wine, it asked to install using sudo wget (https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), and since I cant use sudo wget it doesn't work. Meanwhile installing wine without sudo returns no permission error.

Comment: Why not install Wine from the software store in Ubuntu? What does Wine have to do with it? The info you posted says you are trying to download Chrome.

Comment: @David Wine and Chrome here only serve as an example, the main problem is the fact that sudo wget always return that SSL error. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Well your question is just confusing if it is not real. Please edit the question and only have the necessary info in it.

Comment: Oh, no need for sudo: just download the file with wget and then use sudo to move it to the target directory. You never need to run wget with sudo.